# setup signserver on mac get exception EJBCLIENT000025

Tags: trusted-timestamp

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

I follow the [signserver install guide](https://www.signserver.org/doc/current/manual/installguide.html) to install signserver on my mac,everything runs well,i can access the website, but when i execute this command it's wrong.

```
bin/signserver getstatus brief all
```

ant the result:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.signserver.cli.spi.UnexpectedCommandFailureException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:signserver, moduleName:SignServer-ejb, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@74650e52
at org.signserver.admin.cli.defaultimpl.GetStatusCommand.execute(GetStatusCommand.java:96)
at org.signserver.cli.CommandLineInterface.execute(CommandLineInterface.java:97)
at org.signserver.admin.cli.AdminCLI.main(AdminCLI.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:signserver, moduleName:SignServer-ejb, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@74650e52
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:774)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:116)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getGlobalConfiguration(Unknown Source)
at org.signserver.admin.cli.defaultimpl.GetStatusCommand.execute(GetStatusCommand.java:72)
... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:signserver, moduleName:SignServer-ejb, distinctName:]` typically means that the SignServer CLI can not communicate with the application (SignServer) in the application server.

This could for instance mean that the application server is not running or that the application has not deployed/started up correctly.

Check the server log for any error message. The location of the server if you re using JBoss AS, EAP or WildFly is APPSRV_HOME/standalone/server.log. If everything is fine you should have something like "signserver.ear deployed" near the end and if not check for the first error message.

Before the errors in the server log has been resolved and the application has deployed correctly there is no point in trying to run the SignServer CLI.